# modify several file names using shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, file-rename

I would like to change several files name in my current directory, like this for example : 
test1 
test2 
test3

And I would like to rename every file with a command (mv I think) to have that (for example) : 
foo1 
for2 
foo3

Can you help me ? Thanks in advance

Comment: -1 very low quality of question, bad tags, batch is not bash, shell is not Linux shell, a shell is a shell.

Comment: My tags were wrong, but it doesn't change the quality of the question. and you don't answer it. inappropriate aggressiveness...

Comment: At least I've commented my downvote. A question without specifying the Language/OS using a comment or a tag or a code exmaple to give the opportunity to the users to understand what you really need is a low quality, I'm not agressive. PS: Sorry for my english.

Comment: This is my first comment ever and I'm new on this website and on this environment ... Shell / batch were enough to solve the question. If I knew everything I wouldn't have asked the question...

Comment: No need to be a experimented user to make a good question. regards.

Comment: No but lack of experience can cause people to ask unaccurate questions. like me. doesn't mean the question is "very low quality"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a loop and parameter expansion, like this:

```
for f in test*; do mv "$f" "${f/test/foo}"; done
```

See also http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

Answer (score 1):

Syntax :

```
rename oldname newname *.files
```

For example : rename all *.bak file as *.txt, enter:

```
$ rename .bak .txt *.bak
```

Comment: I didn't knew this tool. <br> Hope cygdrive supports it. Thanks !

Comment: Looks like it doesn't exist on cygdrive, I only have "renameutils" package with commands qmv, imv, and icp. Or maybe there's a trick with  batch to do that ?